# Calculating variable in math equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I am not good with math, I have this equation (very simple to most) but I need help on how to get the value of x

```
10 = x - (1.29 + 4.99% of x)
```

my question is how to calculate x IOW what is the formula used to get the value of x, if that makes sense?

Thank you.

Comment: convert $4.99%$ to decimal form which is just $.0499$. So your equation is just $10=x-(1.29+0.0499x)$ which then becomes $10=x-1.29-0.0499x$. Combine like terms and solve.

Answer (score 2):

$4.99 \% = \dfrac{4.99\%}{100\%} = 0.0499$.

So your equation becomes:

$$10=x-(1.29+0.0499x) \iff 10 = x - 1.29 - 0.0499x$$

Combining "like terms"

$$\iff 10 = (1 - 0.0499)x - 1.29 = 0.9501x - 1.29$$

Now add $1.29$ to both sides of the above equation to get:

$$10 + 1.29 = 0.9501 x \iff 11.29 = 0.9501 x$$

Then divide both sides by $0.9501$ to obtain $x$:

$$\dfrac{11.29}{0.9501} = x$$

Comment: Why has this gone without an UV? +1